# About positivity of a solution to a sub-critical semilinear elliptic problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a non-empty open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$ with $N\ge 3$.
Let $f:\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that

1. $\exists a,b>0, \exists\alpha\in(0,\frac{N+2}{N-2}), \forall x \in\Omega, \forall t\ge0, f(x,t)\le a+bt^\alpha;$
2. $\forall x\in\Omega, \forall t<0, f(x,t)=0.$

Let $\lambda<\lambda_1(\Omega)$, where $\lambda_1(\Omega)$ is the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ on $H^1_0(\Omega)$.

Suppose that $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ is such that:
$$\forall\varphi\in H^1_0(\Omega), \int_\Omega\nabla u(x)\cdot \nabla \varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x=\lambda \int_\Omega u(x) \varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x+\int_\Omega f(x,u(x))\varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x$$

Then, by a bootstrap argument (see Nonlinear Analysis and Semilinear Elliptic Problem by Antonio Ambrosetti and Andrea Malchiodi, page 11, Theorem 1.16), we deduce that $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ and so also for almost every $x\in\Omega$ we have that:
$$-\Delta u(x)=\lambda u(x)+f(x,u(x)).$$

> I want to prove that $u\ge0$.

What i tried so far is the following.

First, $u\in C(\Omega)$, and so $D:=\{x\in\Omega\ |\ u(x)<0\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$.

Now, suppose that $D\neq\emptyset$ to get a contradition. Then $\partial D\subset \{x\in\Omega\ |\ u(x)=0 \}\cup\partial\Omega$ and so I've thought that $v:=u|_D\in H^1_0(D)$. If so, then:
$$\forall\varphi\in H^1_0(D), \int_\Omega\nabla v(x)\cdot \nabla \varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x=\lambda \int_\Omega v(x) \varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x+\int_\Omega f(x,v(x))\varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x \\ = \lambda \int_\Omega v(x) \varphi(x)\operatorname{d}x$$
and so $v$ is an eigenfunction relative to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ of the operator $-\Delta$ defined on $H^1_0(D)$. But by [the characterization by the Rayleigh quotient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1342044/if-l-i-is-the-first-weak-eigenvalue-of-delta-in-a-domain-g-i-and-g-1-su?rq=1) of the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ on an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, we have that $\lambda_1(\Omega)\le\lambda_1(D)$. However: $\lambda<\lambda_1(\Omega)\le\lambda_1(D)\le\lambda$, absurd. Then we have $D=\emptyset$ and the conclusion follows.

> Problem: I've no idea how to prove that $v\in H^1_0(D)$.

In fact, it seems that this could be not the case, as we can guess by the (only, so far) answer to this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3046042/if-u-in-h1-0-omega-cap-c-omega-is-it-true-that-u-in-h1-0-u0).

> Can we somehow fix the previous argument to get the conclusion? Or maybe can anyone provide another argument?

**EDIT: the answer given by ktoi to the related question show that actually $v\in H^1_0(D)$ and then completes the argument given above.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to prove $v\in H^1_0(\Omega$, but your hypothesis $\lambda<\lambda_1(\Omega)$ lends a solution in any case.  Choosing the $H^1_0(\Omega)$ function $\varphi=\min(u,0)$ gives $\int_\Omega |D\varphi|^2=\lambda \int_\Omega \varphi^2$.  From the variational principle, this forces either $\lambda=\lambda_1(\Omega)$ or $\varphi\equiv 0$.